# Posting from dynamic form (Multiple rows)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a form that creates form rows (fields) dynamically (add-delete) up to seven. Each additional form row has an incrimental number appended to it (ie: name="product" next is name="product2".. "Product3" etc.). So I thought I would just use isset to see what is posted and only insert what is posted but my lack of skills has led to this not working. See my code below:

```
    mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO shipped (id, type, client, product, color, quantity)
    VALUES ('$_POST[productid]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[client]','$_POST[product]','$_POST[color]','$_POST[quantity]')";
    if( isset($_POST['productid2']) ) {
    "INSERT INTO shipped (id, type, client, product, color, quantity)
    VALUES ('$_POST[productid2]','$_POST[type2]','$_POST[client2]','$_POST[product2]','$_POST[color2]','$_POST[quantity2]')";
    }
```

I planned to just add "isset" for each product but as it turns out this will only insert one of the set of post values and not both. I am going to have up to product7 (so seven inserts at max). Any help?

Comment: PHP has support for array based field names, try using "product[]" and in the form handler just iterate over them.

Comment: @AlexLunix: why didn't you add that as an answer? Why a comment?

Comment: are u just checking that whether these posted data has values or not?

Comment: @DigitalAssets The values were being posted fine before I added the [] to each of the field names, So I would assume everything is still fine. And the product value is getting inserted

Comment: if it is inserted in to the database, then what are u getting wrong? please explain a little bit, so that we might help u.

Comment: @DigitalAssets The problem is that only product value (column) is being inserted. All the other values for the row are 'Array[0]'

Comment: @ScottSaunders I was in a hurry at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did like the other answer as it seemed much more elegant than the solution I ended up using - but the fact is the other answer just did not work. So my solution just ended up just checking if the next form set of form fields is set, and if it is it displays the proper inserts. See the first part here:

```
mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);

if( !isset($_POST['productid2']) ) {
$sql="INSERT INTO shipped (id, type, client, product, color, quantity)
VALUES ('$_POST[productid]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[client]','$_POST[product]','$_POST[color]','$_POST[quantity]')";
}

if( isset($_POST['productid2']) ) {
$sql="INSERT INTO shipped (id, type, client, product, color, quantity)
VALUES ('$_POST[productid]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[client]','$_POST[product]','$_POST[color]','$_POST[quantity]'),
('$_POST[productid2]','$_POST[type2]','$_POST[client2]','$_POST[product2]','$_POST[color2]','$_POST[quantity2]')";
}

if( isset($_POST['productid3']) ) {
$sql="INSERT INTO shipped (id, type, client, product, color, quantity)
VALUES ('$_POST[productid]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[client]','$_POST[product]','$_POST[color]','$_POST[quantity]'),
('$_POST[productid2]','$_POST[type2]','$_POST[client2]','$_POST[product2]','$_POST[color2]','$_POST[quantity2]'),
('$_POST[productid3]','$_POST[type3]','$_POST[client3]','$_POST[product3]','$_POST[color3]','$_POST[quantity3]')";
}
```

Like this another four times... adding the other values each time. This works for me because my form fields can only be added a max of seven times so it doesn't need to be infinite. So if you are only allowing a small amount of form fields to be added this will work well.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the array in input fields

```
<input type="text" name="productid[]" />
<input type="text" name="type[]" />
<input type="text" name="client[]" />
<input type="text" name="product[]" />
<input type="text" name="color[]" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" />
```

At server side:

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $k => $v){
   $sql="INSERT INTO shipped (id, type, client, product, color, quantity) VALUES 
       ($_POST['productid'][$k],$_POST['type'][$k],$_POST[client][$k]','$v','$_POST[color][$k]','$_POST[quantity][$k]')";

}
```

Comment: This wont work because I am sending the values through post as the value with a incremental number appended to them. I need to be able to post values if a certain post isset.

Comment: dont send the incremental number.. why do you need it anyway!!

Comment: I am using jquery on my form to copy values. But then again my php skills aren't that great, so I am going to give this a try. Will get back to you in a minute here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but I tried this and it is inputting 'Array[0]' into the db for the entries? See the code I used in my answer

Comment: which field is going in as 'Array[0]' ? also since we are directly accessing the elements by key we dont need to initialize them in the loop. see my updated answer

Comment: Sounds good, I tried the updated code (Which looks much simpler :)). But the only value that gets inserted is product everything else is inserted as Array[0]

Comment: I took this code and made two fresh files and tried to use it to insert and it doesn't work. The server side code has a couple errors too (missing quotes around the Post values). But even after fixing that it only will insert the product value column and all other values are inserted as Array[0]

Comment: Then definitely you are doing something wrong in your html.It seems in your code `$_POST['quantity'][$k]` itself is an array. Post your html/jquery and also in serverside `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);` and post the result you get

Comment: please take the code you provided and test it. It does not work. I appreciate the help though.